# Use Embedded Linux image in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, embedded-linux

Hi I am using yocto linux on an embedded hardware with SBC. I have the linux runnin g from the SD card.

Is it possible to use this SD card image to load in virtualbox in my windows system for faster compilation ?

Comment: Using SD card to launch stored image in virtualbox? I guess answer is "yes", because every OS now support reading SD cards.

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Hi it not about reading the SD Card, i want the Embedded Linux that is inside the SD card to be up and running on my VirtualBox.

Comment: My SBC is slow and compiling code on it is taking a long time. SO wanted to check if the same OS can be run on my system which is much more powerful to compile it faster.

Comment: If it is just for compilation, use standard Linux image (ubuntu) in VM and use cross compilers from ubuntu to compile your code

Comment: Yes, that is the obvious solution, and thats how i had been using for a long time but recently GPB was upgraded to latest version and it is not compatable with my Linux. either i had to upgrade my OS which means a lot of changes. or was hoping to load the embedded OS to VM if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the SD Image is Linux compiled for that SBC. Virtualbox gives you a virtual machine for the hardware for your windows machine. So the Linux that runs on your Virtualbox has to be a Linux executable for your windows machine hardware. Linux is portable to different processors as source, but the binary executable is for specific hardware.

Last time I used Yocto for the iMX6 it was intended to cross-compile, run on a PC, but build for the embedded processor. And as a note, I found the Yocto built very slowly on VM, even on a fast P with lots of resources allocated to the VM. I ended up using a desktop running Linux directly, not as a VM, as my build machine. I definitely wouldn't want to build Yocto on a SBC.